# Default Redis behaviour on graceful shutdown

Tags: linux, database, redis

What is the default behaviour of Redis when a graceful shutdown is committed?

Let's say there are a bunch of keys in Redis. Then due to maintenance needs, the machine needs to be soft rebooted. All services are gracefully killed and the machine boots again. Are the keys still available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is configured for data persistence as a default, so yes - the keys would still be there after a reboot. If you want to change this behavior, review your `redis.conf` file after reading this blog post: http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html